# How to link css file in asp.net project?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have `Index.cshtml` file and I want to include `login.css` file there. Index.cshtml lives on `Views/Home`. I created `login.css` file in `Views/Home/css` folder. Here is how I linked it on Index.cshtml:

```
<link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But it doesn't work. When I writes styles inside `Index.cshtml`, it works perfectly. Where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would not put your css in the Views folder.  This would belong at the root of the website project(wwwroot).  This way you would reference your external styles like this:

```
<link href="~/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: It is worth nothing that Razor (the view engine) will pick up the `~` and convert it to the virtual directory that the application is running in. E.g. if it runs in `/` then `~/` becomes `/`, and if the application lives under `/My/Special/Site/` then `~/` becomes `/My/Special/Site/`.

Answer (score 2):

You can juste drags you file css file into yous cshtml file and VS to the work for u